# Strange message from facebook messenger api

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger

For some reason I receive message from facebook page (with connected bot):

> "Thanks for messaging us. We try to be as responsive as possible. We'll get back to you soon."

But in bot app there is no such phrase.

Whether he can send a facebook message under some conditions (such as long response from webhook)?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guesssing it's an old auto response setting for that page.

Go into settings and under Response Assistant, set both of these to No:

> Stay responsive when you can't get to your computer or phone
>
> Send Instant Replies to anyone who messages your Page

Comment: Can you send screenshot?

Comment: Did you see the last things on the bottom of this screenshot? http://i.imgur.com/SzGNfJc.png You need to switch it off